# enumerate hashset and delete elements from it

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

I want to go through a HashSet and make a (complicated) check on each element which results in saving the element, removing the element from the HashSet or doing nothing.

Since a foreach loop does not allow me to change the HashSet and an index is not available, I do not know how to perform the task (without doing slow things like copying the HashSet first or applying several LINQ operations which means enumerating the HashSet more than once).

Any suggestions?

Comment: `saving the element` where do you want to save element? Assuming when you do nothing it's being *saved* in hashset

Comment: No, I want to find and save the "best" element from the HashSet in some optimization sense, where I go through a multi-step procedure, deleting all elements that have already exceeded the best possible value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use [RemoveWhere()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361254.aspx) with an appropriate predicate function.

You can have a side-effect of your predicate which copies the element being checked (assuming that's what you mean by "save the element"), if needed. Perhaps that sounds a little hacky, but it would work fine I think.

This works because your predicate function will be presented with each element of the HashSet in an undefined order, and therefore you can decide what to do with each element, as well as returning `true` to delete it and `false` to keep it.

[EDIT] Here's a code sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hashSet = new HashSet<int> {4, 0, 6, -1, 23, -8, 14, 12, -9, 5, 2};
            var itemProcessor = new ItemProcessor();

            hashSet.RemoveWhere(itemProcessor.Process);

            Console.WriteLine("Max = {0}, Min = {1}", itemProcessor.Max, itemProcessor.Min);
            Console.WriteLine("\nHashSet contents:");

            foreach (int number in hashSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class ItemProcessor
    {
        private int max = int.MinValue;
        private int min = int.MaxValue;

        // Removes all negative numbers and calculates max and min values.

        public bool Process(int item)
        {
            max = Math.Max(item, max);
            min = Math.Min(item, min);

            return (item < 0);
        }

        public int Max { get { return max; } }
        public int Min { get { return min; } }
    }
}
```